# A concise, clear list of what is new in JPA2?

Tags: java, orm, jpa, jakarta-ee, jpa-2.0

Does anybody know of a good list of what is new in JPA 2?  Not what is new with Hibernate/TopLink in the  version that supports JPA 2 but what is new in the actual spec.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The link mentioned in the accepted answer doesn't say anything about the second level cache so I decided to post a quick list to summarize "What's new in JPA 2.0 (JSR-317)":

- **Standard properties** for `persistence.xml` - E.g. `javax.persistence.jdbc.driver`, etc instead of persistence provider specific properties.
- Mixed **Access** Type - `PROPERTY` and `FIELD` access type can be mixed in a hierarchy and combined in a single class.
- **Derived Identifiers** - Identifiers can be derived from relationships.
- **`@ElementCollection`**, **`@OrderColumn`** - For better collection support.
- **Unidirectional `@OneToMany`** / **`@OneToOne`** - For expanded mappings.
- Shared Cache API - **Second level caching** in JPA, **yeah**!
- Locking - Support for **pessimistic** locking added.
- **Enhanced JP QL** - Timestamp literals, non-polymorphic queries, collection parameter in IN expression, ordered list index, CASE statement.
- Expression and Criteria API - **`QueryBuilder`** and **`CriteriaQuery`** for programmatic construction of type-safe queries.
- API additions - Additional API on **`EntityManager`** (supported properties, `detach` method, etc)  and **`Query`** (query hints).
- **Validation** - Transparent support of Bean Validation (JSR-303) if provider is present. (Validation is optional, the JPA 2.0 spec does not require a Bean Validation implementation).

Comment: Nice overview. There was also something with 1:1 jointables. But I think you already covered it in the `@OneToOne`. The Bean Validation is by the way part of JSR-303 (JPA2 itself is JSR-317).

Comment: @BalusC Thanks. And you're right, the wording about Validation was confusing. What's new in JPA 2.0 is the transparent support of Bean Validation, not Bean Validation itself. I hope it's more clear.